# Count unique event per month

Tags: mysql

Im trying to find the total count of event names.  My table has a column Royalty_Month and Event_Combined.  If an event appears in Month A, I dont want to count it in Month B.

This is the query I have, but its not excluding events that occurred in the previous months.

```
SELECT
    Royalty_Month,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(Event_Combined)) As Event_Count
    FROM Agency   
    GROUP BY Royalty_Month
    ORDER BY Royalty_Month ASC
```

Sample Data:

| Royalty_Month | Event_Combined |
| --- | --- |
| 2010-05-01 | Event A |
| 2010-06-01 | Event B |
| 2010-07-01 | Event C |
| 2010-07-01 | Event B |
| 2010-07-01 | Event D |
| 2010-07-01 | Event D |
| 2010-07-01 | Event D |
| 2010-07-01 | Event E |
| 2010-07-01 | Event E |
| 2010-07-01 | Event E |
| 2010-07-01 | Event E |
| 2010-07-01 | Event E |
| 2010-08-01 | Event F |
| 2010-08-01 | Event F |
| 2010-09-01 | Event E |
| 2010-09-01 | Event E |
| 2010-09-01 | Event G |
| 2010-09-01 | Event G |
| 2010-09-01 | Event G |
| 2010-09-01 | Event H |
| 2010-09-01 | Event H |
| 2010-09-01 | Event H |
| 2010-10-01 | Event E |
| 2010-10-01 | Event F |
| 2010-10-01 | Event G |
| 2010-10-01 | Event G |

Expected Output:

| Royalty_Month | Total_Events |
| --- | --- |
| 2010-05-01 | 1 |
| 2010-06-01 | 1 |
| 2010-07-01 | 3 |
| 2010-08-01 | 1 |
| 2010-09-01 | 2 |
| 2010-10-01 | 0 |

Comment: Can you share a sample input table?

Comment: Please provide sample data, DDL + DML commands

Comment: @lemon added sample data csv

Comment: @learning added sample data

Comment: Please write it out, instead of attaching the file. thanks

Comment: Please share sample data script.

Comment: @learning how is that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count rows by `month`, use default `group by month` - this will group all rows which fall in a single month.

To fetch the count of rows in a single month, your query should be

```
SELECT Royalty_Month, count(Event_Combined) as total FROM agency
group by Royalty_Month, MONTH(Royalty_Month) // full group by
ORDER BY Royalty_Month ASC
```

which will generate

[image]

[Live example](https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3ysaqf27n)

Read more on default date time functions [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)

Comment: no, Im trying to get total events for each month, excluding an event name that appears in a prior month

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.0, one option is to:

- retrieve first time an event appears, using a ranking value given by the `ROW_NUMBER` window function
- count only first appearances for each day, with a conditional sum of 1s

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Event_Combined ORDER BY Royalty_Month) AS rn
    FROM tab
)
SELECT Royalty_Month,
       SUM(IF(rn = 1, 1, 0)) AS Total_Events
FROM cte
GROUP BY Royalty_Month
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this on previous versions as well as new version of MySQL:

```
SELECT  CurrMonth,  SUM(CASE WHEN Event_PrevMonth IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)TOTAL_EVENTS
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT A1.Event_Combined, A1.Royalty_Month CurrMonth, A2.Event_Combined Event_PrevMonth , A2.Royalty_Month Prev_month
    FROM Agency A1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT Event_Combined, Royalty_Month 
        FROM Agency
    )A2 ON A1.Event_Combined = A2.Event_Combined AND A1.Royalty_Month > A2.Royalty_Month
) T 
GROUP BY CurrMonth;
```